# Saving data to Mysql with SpringBoot

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

[image]

Please consider the following scenario

I would like to be able to search an employee by Id and get Employee details, but also Contact Details associated with that Employee. Same for Owner. Would be the same job.

I would like to search for telephone number and find the employee or the owner and get all details associated with that record.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    public boolean isNew() {
        return this.id == null;
    }
}

@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@MappedSuperclass
public class Person extends BaseEntity {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    // maybe other fields
}

public class Owner extends Person{
    private String emailAddress;
    private String mobileTelNo;
    private String homeTelNo;
    private String workTelNo;
        @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Employee employee;
}

@Data
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    private ContactDetails contactDetails;

@Data
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ContactDetails extends BaseEntity {
    private String emailAddress;
    private String mobileTelNo;
    private String homeTelNo;
    private String workTelNo;
    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Employee employee;
}
}


public interface UsersRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Integer> {
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/users")
public class UsersController {

    @Autowired
    UsersRepository usersRepository;

    @GetMapping(value = "/all")
    public List<Employee> getAll() {
        return usersRepository.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/load")
    public List<Employee> persist(@RequestBody final Employee employee) {
        usersRepository.save(employee);
        return usersRepository.findAll();
    }

}
```

How could I map my entities to achieve this result?

**Update**

when using the following json

```
I would like to save a record like this using the /load endpoint

{
   "id": 2,
   "firstName": "Scilla",
   "lastName": "Biffolia",
   "middleName": "None",
   "alias": "Cr",
   "dateOfBirth": "2020-02-12",
   "gender": "male",
   "contactDetails": {
       "emailAddress": "scilla@stack.com"
   }
}
```

But I get this result back

```
[
   {
       "id": 2,
       "firstName": null,
       "lastName": null,
       "middleName": null,
       "alias": null,
       "dateOfBirth": null,
       "gender": null,
       "contactDetails": {
           "id": 8,
           "emailAddress": "scilla@stack.com",
           "mobileTelNo": null,
           "homeTelNo": null,
           "workTelNo": null,
           "employee": null,
           "new": false
       },
       "new": false
   }
]
```

I can see that my CustomerDetails table has been updated.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a better way than this?
Based on the previous answer.

```
   @Data
   @Entity
   @AllArgsConstructor
   @NoArgsConstructor
   @Builder
   public class Owner extends Person {
   
       @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
       private ContactDetails contactDetails;
   }
   
   @Data
   @Entity
   @AllArgsConstructor
   @NoArgsConstructor
   public class ContactDetails extends BaseEntity {
       private String emailAddress;
       private String mobileTelNo;
       private String homeTelNo;
       private String workTelNo;
   
       @OneToOne(mappedBy = "contactDetails", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
       @JsonIgnore
       private Owner owner;
   }
```